# mod_rewrite problems - redirect subdomain to different domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I must have a brain freeze as I can not get my rewrite rules working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.otherdomain.com/ [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/otherdomain [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.otherdomain.com/ [R=permanent,L]
```

What I want is essential to redirect

otherdomain.example.com and example.com/otherdomain to otherdomain.com

Comment: So .. do they work but incorrectly .. or they do not work at all? Do you have other rules there? DO they work (if you comment those domain redirects)?

Comment: They are completely ignored. I have removed all other redirects/rewrite stuff from the .htaccess file.

Comment: /slap self... My subfolder "otherdomain" contained a .htaccess file that overwrote the one in the root. (I have been trying to upload a complete website mirror "otherdomain.com" to another webhost, so all I would need would be switch DNS incase of webserver troubles at my current webhost.)

Comment: I just always thought that .htaccess were handled like this: /.htaccess and *then* /otherdomain/.htaccess (i.e. so the one in root would always be processed first)

Comment: Nope -- global (virtual host) first, then .htaccess; rewriting rules in subfolder will have priority and parent rewriting rules will be ignored unless `RewriteOptions` directive is used: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below redirection. will work 100%. Because I personally use it for my website....

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.old-main-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subname\.old-main-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```